# Selenium web scraping in Python hangs

Tags: jquery, python, html, selenium

I'm scraping a website where I have to fill in a form before seeing the data I need. When I click the submit button on the form, a dialog window pops up to show that the data for the next page is loading. Once it has loaded, the browser navigates to the new page.

Here's the submit button html:

```
<input id="form_submit" type="submit" onclick="$('#loading_screen').dialog('open');" name="submitLink" value="Search"></input>
```

My problem is that sometimes the browser doesn't navigate to the next page, and just hangs, showing the dialog, and in the bottom left of the browser, it says "waiting for website.com..."

I've tried driver.set_page_load_timeout(10), but the page just seems to hang forever and no TimeoutException is raised.

Is there a way I could check to see if the dialog still exists after a set amount of time and if so refresh the page? Do you see any other way I could ensure I can check to see if the page is hanging? Thanks!

Comment: Is it consistent in both Chrome and Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: it works with chrome, but not with firefox. do you know which phantomjs is built on top of? that's the one I'll eventually be using, so it wouldn't be a problem if it's built on chrome, but could be if built on firefox